# Is there any book as Landau's for Physics but for Chemistry?

Tags: books

Landau's series of books are a collection of books that describe briefly but very deeply the core part of the main fields of Physics. He wrote them rigorously and they are very very abstract. He gave Physics new approaches in those books. If you want to understand them, your starting point should be knowing all those main fields of Physics previously.

Is there any book like it but in Chemistry?

Thank you all!

Comment: Groups Theory by Cotton, Szabo for Q mechanics, I don't know a nice book for statistical thermodynamics...maybe Terrell Hill intro to statist thermodynamics, although I don't like it..

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303/31775

Comment: Feynman's introduction to his "Lectures on Physics" gives a hint why there cannot be such a book for chemistry:

Comment: ‘This is one of the most fantastic pieces of detective work that has ever been done – organic chemistry… The physicist could never quite believe that the chemist knew what he was talking about when he described the arrangement of the atoms. For about twenty years it has been possible, in some cases, to look at such molecules by a physical method, and it has been possible to locate every atom, not by looking at colors, but by measuring where they are. And lo and behold!, the chemists are almost always correct.’

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry)

Comment: Chemistry is as much an artisanry, a handicraft as it is science. Pure rigour get's you nowhere, except for the development of fundamental understanding in physical chemistry (statistical mechanics, QM, etc.).